# Query with Group By clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

My table has the last_updated_date, department and some other fields, I want to write a query get all the columns, in each department's highest last_updated_row. I tried to write with a group by clause, I am not getting all the rows.

```
   id   name    department      last_updated_date
    1   Manu    Maths       22/01/2019
    2   Anil    Maths       23/01/2019
    3   Kala    Maths       24/01/2019

    4   Deepak  Science     22/02/2019
    5   Krish   Science     23/02/2019
    6   Kannan  Science     24/02/2019

    7   Sai     English     02/12/2018
    8   Sunil   English     03/12/2018
    9   Mala    English     04/12/2018
    10  Kola    English     04/12/2018
```

I want to return

```
    3   Kala    Maths       24/01/2019
    6   Kannan  Science     24/02/2019
    9   Mala    English     04/12/2018
or
    10  Kola    English     04/12/2018
```

If two last_updated_date are the same, the query should retrieve any one of the last_updated_date.

Here I am using the timestamp for the date field. so my last_modified_date looks like 2019-02-07 17:26:49.209

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the expected result in case of a tie? Add the row (10, Kola, English, 04/12/2018) to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by department order by last_updated_date desc) as rn from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

or you can use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a 
  where last_updated_date in (select max(last_updated_date) from tablenamae b where a.department=b.department)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres this type of query is typically most efficient using `distinct on ()`

```
select distinct on (department) * 
from the_table
order by department, last_updated desc;
```